# pagespeed mod - Optimization of resources

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup the pagespeed mod for apache to help optimize my site. Currently my core domain is http://www.example.com. However, I have a separate domain which serves up the resources (e.g. css, js, images, etc). This domain is http://www.example_static.com. Pagespeed mod doesn't seem to combine the css being served by this domain, even though it resides on the same server and is also setup for pagespeed. Is there a special process if serving content from an *external* domain?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I needed to specify the domains using:

```
ModPagespeedDomain *example.com
ModPagespeedDomain *example_static.com.
```

in my /etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf file.

More info on this can be found here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains